# syntaxerror: unexpected character after line continuation character in python

Tags: python, file

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this program? I face

```
syntaxerror unexpected character after line continuation character
```

when I run this program:

```
f = open(D\\python\\HW\\2_1 - Copy.cp,"r");  
lines = f.readlines();

for i in lines:  
    thisline = i.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to quote that filename:

```
f = open("D\\python\\HW\\2_1 - Copy.cp", "r")
```

Otherwise the bare backslash after the D is interpreted as a line-continuation character, and should be followed by a newline. This is used to extend long expressions over multiple lines, for readability:

```
print "This is a long",\
      "line of text",\
      "that I'm printing."
```

Also, you shouldn't have semicolons (`;`) at the end of your statements in Python.

Comment: -1 (1) Didn't mention missing colon (2) Backslashes not needed inside [], () and {}

Comment: @John Machin: Thanks, I didn't know about (2). Fixed. I didn't want to address everything in the question, but added text about semicolon since I didn't keep it in my suggested fix.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

`f = open(D\\python\\HW\\2_1 - Copy.cp,"r");`

by

`f = open("D:\\python\\HW\\2_1 - Copy.cp", "r")`

1. File path needs to be a string (constant)
2. need colon in Windows file path
3. space after comma for better style
4. ; after statement is allowed but fugly.

What tutorial are you using?

Comment: actually, 1 don't use any tutorial.just search in internet and try to understand how is programming in python

Comment: Then may I suggest that you do something a bit more structured: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 0):

The filename should be a string. In other names it should be within quotes.

```py
f = open("D\\python\\HW\\2_1 - Copy.cp","r")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in lines:
    thisline = i.split(" ");
```

You can also open the file using `with`

```py
with open("D\\python\\HW\\2_1 - Copy.cp","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        thisline = i.split(" ");
```

There is no need to add the semicolon(`;`) in python. It's ugly.