# input() - unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, string, input

Ok I've search for this one for quite some time but have not been able to resolve this issue. I am sure that this issue lies with input().

```
networkPath = input("Drop Path: ")
print("test") # <- will never get here
```

*SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character*

Also, if the user puts their input in quotes this error does not occur.
Such as seen here: [syntaxerror: unexpected character after line continuation character in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880781/syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character-in-python)

I do not want the user to have to wrap their input in quotes. The reasoning is that they will be putting in long network paths such as: \oursite.com\someplace\global\Communications\News\Sitemap

Now I know you are thinking, "why can't they just wrap in quotes?" The reasoning is that they would be copying and pasting that network path from a generated email.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I should note that this fails in windows command line and not in pyscripter

Comment: what are some example inputs that fail on your script? Alone, your snippet works just fine (I assume you're using Python 3?)

Comment: As a side note, even forcing the users to wrap their strings in quotes wouldn't help—as soon as someone types in some path like `"\foo\bar"`, you won't get backslashes and f's and b's, but formfeed and backspace characters.

Comment: @MattDMo for example: \\oursite.com\someplace\global\Communications\News\Sitemap

Answer (score 3):

The root problem here is almost certainly that you're learning Python 3, but trying to use a Python 2.7 interpreter to do it. Don't do that. Go [download Python 3.3](http://python.org/download/) or later and use that.

But if you're actually intentionally trying to use Python 2.7, read on:

---

> I am sure that this issue lies with input().

You're right. As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) says, `input` is:

> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

In other words, whatever the user types in gets passed to [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). Which means it's being evaluated as Python code. And, unless the user happens to type something that's valid Python code (like a string in quotes), you will get a `SyntaxError`.

The solution here is simple: Don't use `input`, use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

---

(Note that Python 3's `input` is the same as Python 2's `raw_input`, and it doesn't have any equivalent to Python 2's `input`. This is why I believe you're using the wrong Python version.)

Comment: You are correct, I am using the wrong version! so the reason it works in Pyscripter is that it is in fact using 3.x, while anything ran from the command line is running 2.7!

Comment: @LokiIkol: On non-Windows systems, it's usually a matter of running `python3` instead of `python`. On Windows, if your 3.x is 3.3 (or if you've installed the launcher tool for old versions), see [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) for details. 3.4 will give you a simpler option, but it's still in beta. Or you can use [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to make your life easier. Or, if you don't actually need that Python 2.7, just uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use input() for this; use raw_input(). Input() calls eval() on the read-in text, which you neither need or want , and which is responsible for this error.

Comment: note that this is only true when using Python 2.x, in Py3 `input()` does what the OP is wanting to do