# Clean text with python

Tags: python

I wanna removes all words with numbers in them and also makes all words lowercase.
Codes as:

```
#remove words with numbers
import re
lower_alpha = lambda x: re.sub(r\"\"\"\\w*\\d\\w*\"\"\", ' ', x.lower())
data['reviews'] = data.reviews.map(lower_alpha)
data.head()
```

But the error shows like:

> lower_alpha = lambda x: re.sub(r\"\"\"\w*\d\w*\"\"\", ' ',
>   x.lower())^
>
> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

And there are some useless 
 in the text, I use following codes to remove it:

```
#remove <br>    
remove_br = lambda x: re.sub(r\"\"\" br \"\"\", ' ', x.lower())
data['reviews'] = data.reviews.map(remove_br)
data.head()
```

Error shows:

> remove_br = lambda x: re.sub(r\"\"\" br \"\"\", ' ', x.lower())^
>   SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Almost same as the previous one. So is there anybody profession can help me to figure out what's wrong with these?

The dataframe is an excel sheet like:
User_id  Stars  reviews

- User_id  Stars  reviews
- xxx        5      xxxxx
- xxx        5      xxxxx
- xxx        5      xxxxx
- xxx        4      xxxxx
- ...        ..     .....

Comment: `r\"\"...` is a `SyntaxError`.  You need to start with the quote first: `r"\"\"...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntaxerror: unexpected character after line continuation character in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880781/syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo with `r\"\"\"\\w*\\d\\w*\"\"\"` — first `\` treated in special way. Is you're using raw string, just go with `r'\"\"\\w*\\d\\w*\"\"\"'` (if it matches your logic)

Comment: Please remove last backslash also, or that would result in `EOL`.

Comment: Thx for pointing out. Not sure what it's meant to be from logic perpective tho, just wrapped with single quotes