# extract number from lanes in a text file in python

Tags: python, regex, text, numbers, line

I have a text file that each line of it is as follows:

```
    <vehicle id="tester.3" x="6936.49" y="10.20" angle="90.00" type="tester" speed="24.87" pos="6336.49" lane="longedge_3" slope="0.00"/>
    <vehicle id="tester.4" x="4388.72" y="7.00" angle="90.00" type="tester" speed="22.57" pos="3788.72" lane="longedge_2" slope="0.00"/>
    <vehicle id="tester.5" x="2075.13" y="13.40" angle="90.00" type="tester" speed="23.30" pos="1475.13" lane="longedge_4" slope="0.00"/>
```

in each line i need to extract the value of speed

the python code i use is

```
import re

with open('fcd.xml') as f:
  a = f.readlines()
  pattern = r'speed=([\d.]+)'

  for line in a:
    print(re.search(pattern, line)[1])
```

The code can't run
it shows the below

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

can anyone help?

Comment: You are not matching the double quotes `speed="([\d.]+)"`

Comment: Why not use an XML parser?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/lxml/

Comment: @Thefourthbird i matched it and now that's the problem


pattern = r"speed="([\d.]+)"
                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: I can not reproduce that. If I create a file `fcd.xml` with your example content the the pattern with quotes it works for me. Did you check for example this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880781/syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
import re

with open('fcd.xml') as f:
  a = f.read()
  pattern = r'speed="([\d.]+)"'
  print(re.findall(pattern, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also i want to put all these values in a list but as numbers not as strings
this code below gets a list but with strings. Is there any other way with regex to get speed as numerical values?

```
import re

text = 'tester.3'

new_list = []
idx = 0

with open('fcd.xml') as f:
    a = f.readlines()
    pattern = r'speed="([\d.]+)"'
    
    for line in a:
        if text in line:
        x=(re.findall(pattern, line))
        new_list.insert(idx, x)
        idx += 1
print(new_list)
```

Comment: To convert all of the speeds to numerical values, do `new_list = [*map(float, new_list)]` at the end before the `print` statement.